# Open the window Using StatusBar in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoUPL.png)

Hi, I'm trying to make a simple app.
But, I have in trouble about the handling NSStatusBar.

At first, when I click the close button of the window, It is disappeared.
Then, I want to open(appear) the window using the NSStatusBar. (NSStatusBar has "open" button.)

But, I have no idea how to handle it.

Is there a way to open the window?

Please give me any advise or reference.
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the first window created?

Comment: It's just in the windowgroup  of @main. When I start the app, the first window is shown.